# System.currentTimeInMillis() not giving accurate value in Android

Tags: java, android

I have an Android app which finds the time interval between two events.
When Event 1 fires a broadcast, I store the current time using System.currentTimeInMillis()
I do the same when the second event occurs and then calculate the difference.
However, the result is always a couple of seconds off, in the sense that I know the interval was around 4 seconds but the value I get is around 6.

Is this because of the delay between sending the broadcast, receiving it and then storing the value?
If so, what's a better way to do it to get a more accurate value?

Answer (score 1):

Per Developer.android.com (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html):

> System.currentTimeMillis() is the standard "wall" clock (time and
>   date) expressing milliseconds since the epoch.  The wall clock can be
>   set by the user or the phone network (see setCurrentTimeMillis(long)),
>   so the time may jump backwards or forwards unpredictably. This clock
>   should only be used when correspondence with real-world dates and
>   times is important, such as in a calendar or alarm clock application.
>   Interval or elapsed time measurements should use a different clock. 
>   If you are using System.currentTimeMillis(), consider listening to the
>   ACTION_TIME_TICK, ACTION_TIME_CHANGED and ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED
>   Intent broadcasts to find out when the time changes.